# SSO Implementation using Tomcat ,Jboss for a application

Tags: java, tomcat, jboss, single-sign-on

Can anyone help me with this.

I want to implement SSO for an java application which i can access through web browser. It has Tomcat and Jboss. What i want is when i login into remote desktop (client machine) & open my application through browser it should not ask my login details again.

It should get authentication from Active Directory.

Comment: Please see this [link](https://developer.jboss.org/wiki/JBossWebSingleSignOn) on how to set up ClusteredSSOValve for your web application. This should get you started. Also see this [link](https://dzone.com/articles/choosing-sso-your-jboss) for a general SSO options discussion.